# General response values of external login api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

Generally, what values providers will be returned in an external login request such as Facebook, Twitter, Google, Microsoft, and etc?

I need a common data model for storing returned values like the following model:

```
ID int(11) AI PK 
UserID int(11) // Local ID of Users table
Provider varchar(255) 
Username varchar(255) // Username of external provider
AccountID varchar(255) // Account ID of external provider
Token varchar(500) // Token of external provider
Created datetime 
Modified datetime
```

another value(s) is needed to save?

Comment: You have to do it manually by creating object of datamodel class. Parse the responses of login and set values to object keys.

Comment: How about OAuth?

Comment: There is no generic structure?

Comment: I dont know about such generic model.

Comment: The minimum common information such as userid, email and etc are used between all based on returned data.